# How to create an HTML document that allow switch themes using pure HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-variables

How to create a document that allow switch themes using HTML and CSS ? (without JavaScript)

I created simple HTML document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        :root { --bg-color: lightgreen; }
        * { background-color: var(--bg-color); }
        /* You can add lines here. */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2 id="theme-1">Theme 1</h2>
        <a href="#theme-1">Theme 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 id="theme-2">Theme 2</h2>
        <a href="#theme-2">Theme 2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 id="no-theme">No theme</h2>
        <a href="#no-theme">No theme</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with `<style>` tag.

I tried to insert this CSS code :

```
        :has(#theme-1:target) { --bg-color: red; }
        :has(#theme-2:target) { --bg-color: blue; }
```

but **no one** browser support `:has` selector.

Then I tried to insert this :

```
        #theme-1:target { --bg-color: red; }
        #theme-2:target { --bg-color: blue; }
```

but it doesn't change `background-color` of `<body>`. It change `<h2>` tags only.

So, how to switch between themes ? Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible: You have to nest everything (or at least everything that should depend on theme). e.g:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #theme-1:target{
        background: red;
      }
      #theme-1:target h2{
        font-family: "Verdana";
      }
      #theme-2:target{
        background: blue;
      }
      #theme-2:target h2{
        font-family: "Times New Roman";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="theme-1"><div id="theme-2">
      <h2>Theme 1</h2>
      <a href="#theme-1">Theme 1</a>    
      <h2>Theme 2</h2>
      <a href="#theme-2">Theme 2</a>    
      <h2 id="no-theme">No theme</h2>
      <a href="#no-theme">No theme</a>
    </div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```